# Type mismatch error twitter4j

Tags: twitter4j

```
 RequestToken requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(callbackURL.toString());
```

im getting a error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from twitter4j.http.RequestToken to twitter4j.auth.RequestToken"
for the above please help

Answer (score 0):

I have identified the issue, the jar file i was using was an older one, twitter4j-core-2.2.5.jar did the job.